# PS1 script stops execution in the middle when run silently

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to set up a PS1 script to restart the Windows service on the remote machine. Script is supposed to be automatically run by PRTG platform (monitoring solution). Platform has built-in feature which allows you start script for you. Problem is that when PRTG runs the script it stops in a half way without error after the ‘Stop-Service’ cmdlet. When I remove it from the script then full script is run. I've tried different variations of the script but it's always like it stops when it finished execution of ‘Stop-Service’.
The script supposed to be run in silent mode by the PRTG. Do you have any idea what can be the cause of it or how to check it?

```
$service = Get-Service -ComputerName 123.123.123.123 -Name Tomcat

Stop-Service -InputObject $service -Force
 
Move-Item -Path "\\123.123.123.123\C$\Program Files (x86)\tomcat\logs\tomcat.log" -Destination "\\123.123.123.123\C$\Program Files (x86)\tomcat\logs\log_archieve"

Get-ChildItem "\\123.123.123.123\C$\Program Files (x86)\tomcat\logs\log_archieve\tomcat.log" | ForEach-Object {          
Rename-Item $_.FullName "$BackupFolder$($_.BaseName -replace " ", "_" -replace '\..*?$')-$(Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyy")_oldlog.log"
}

Start-Service -InputObject $service -Verbose
```

Comment: Is this really your code? Looks like you have copy-pasted this from a website and left all the HTML entities in there like `3&gt;&amp;1`, where in code that does not work of course. Also PLEASE try and format code (use indentation) so it becomes readable

Comment: It;s more than likely that PRTG doens;t have pemrission to stop that service. Regardless, you can track what the script is doing by using the `Start-Transcript` command at the start and setting a log location (use `Stop-Transcript` at the end of the script)

Comment: Theo I've edited the entry post and put better format - code is correct though needed to change it a bit to make neutral.

@Scepticalist I've tried to catch output when script fails without success but I'll give it a shot with `StartTranscript`. The `Stop-Service` cmdlet can be run by the PRTG but the script stops at that stage and doesn't proceed to next lines. When I change the location of `Stop-Sevice` f.e. put it after the `Move-Item` then script again executes anything till `Stop-Service`, completes execution of `Stop-Service` but doesn't move on to `Get-Childitem` and the rest.

Comment: `Stop-Service` waits for the return code - thats why it has a `-NoWait` switch